# Regular Expression to devide string to many strings with special delimiter

Tags: c#, regex

I need regular expression (c#) to split string to 1 or many substrings with
unregular delimiter, for example :

Hello ,[1]Please Help[1]me resolving this[1]regex issue[1], Thank You.

To split to 5 mathces :

1. Hello ,
2. Please Help
3. me resolving this
4. regex issue
5. , Thank You.

Comment: Can't use Split function, because I need index start and length of all Matches, Thanks.

Comment: That is another question, the one above wants to split things. And please don't add information to your question through comments.

Comment: `match1.IndexOf(match1)` will give you start index.

Comment: Sorry about that, I will post new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string input = "Hello ,[1]Please Help[1]me resolving this[1]regex issue[1], Thank You.";
var parts = Regex.Matches(input, @"(.+?)(\[1\]|$)").Cast<Match>()
            .Select(m => m.Groups[1])
            .Select(m => new { m.Index, m.Length, m.Value })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: +1 good solution, and I suggest you to post it to new clarified question of OP

Answer (score 5):

You don't need regular expression here. Use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
 input.Split(new []{ "[1]" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: I didn't mantion that i need the index start and length of all matches, that's why i need regex and not simple Split

Comment: If you don't mind, please provide the real input and output do you expected?

Comment: @user2326167 I think that requirement changes your question dramatically. It's better to ask new one

Comment: What do You mean ? There's a fine example in my post

Comment: @user2326167 in your post I can see only array of strings

Answer (score 0):

instead of string, you can use split function as mentioned below :

```
string data = "Hello ,[1]Please Help[1]me resolving this[1]regex issue[1], Thank You.";
var arrayData = data.Split(new string[] { "[1]" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

**And Using Regular Expression :**

```
string data = "Hello ,[1]Please Help[1]me resolving this[1]regex issue[1], Thank You.";
string[] substrings = Regex.Split(data, @"\[1\]");
```